# Java: Adding Future<obj> to a list

Tags: java, java-8, future, futuretask

Now that I have a handle on retrieving objects in parallel, how can I add those objects to a list?

I have a list of `Future<Site>` objects that I'm attempting to add to an `ArrayList` of `Site` objects. Here's my for loop. I can add a print statement in the loop and it reveals that the list of `Future<Site>` objects is indeed populated, however adding to the existing list (last line) does not work.

```
List<Future<Site>> futures=threadmaker.invokeAll(active_sites.stream().map(site -> new TAG_SCANNER(site, loggr)).collect(Collectors.toList()));

//Now fetch all the results
for (Future<Site> result : futures) {
    //SOUND THE ALARMS (adding to existing list)
    alarm_sites.add(result.get());
}
```

EDIT:

I thought Future's get method was blocking, in that the code would not progress until it returns a result. Does my mistake lie in trying to add to an already existing list?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? any error? What is the type of `alarm_sites`?

Comment: @sidgate It simply doesn't work. No error and nothing gets added to the list. The alarm_sites is a List of Site objects. One interesting thing though is that I can call Site object methods on result.get() and those function properly.

So my thinking is `futures` is a `List<Future<Site>>`, when I iterate over that list, `result` should be a `Future<Site>` object, and when I call `result.get()` I should receive a `Site` object, which I should be able to add to my list, `alarm_sites`.

Answer (score -1):

For some reason, creating the list after my invokeall command solved my issues. I'm not sure why the pre-existing list didn't work but I'm marking the issue as solved for now, and I'll look into this later to see what may have happened.